# Как сделать вот такую сетку на bootstrap?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот эти блоки, для наглядности выделенные разными цветами, как сделать на бутстрап? Получается 4 колонки разных размеров. Какая должна быть разметка и какие классы для блоков?

Comment: учите лучше html и современный css3 а bootstrap выкиньте из головы

Comment: Мне надо именно в данном случае только бутстрап.

Comment: https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.1/layout/grid/